# Java 1.8.0_251 , OSX Catalina, rendering of fonts to offscreen windows broken

Tags: java, macos, macos-catalina

Some combination of the most recent Java and most recent OSX has
severely damaged rendering of fonts to offscreen images.  Can anyone
suggest a workaround until oracle/apple get their act together?

Here's what I see on when rendered to an offscreen image:
[image]

Here's what I see everywhere else, including windows, and if 
rendered directly to the normal window on a mac, instead of 
to a buffer
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which seems to be satisfactory; use implementation
dependent "volatile images" for offscreen drawing.  I cribbed this method
from java's repaint manager:

```
        public static Image getVolatileImage(Component c,int width,int height)
    {
       GraphicsConfiguration config = c.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        if (config == null) {
            config = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
                            getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
        }
       return config.createCompatibleVolatileImage(width, height, Transparency.OPAQUE);
    }
```